# Is it possible to use subjectAltName with one word domains?

Tags: openssl, certificate-authority, self-signed-certificate

I'm running my own CA. My new cert's desired CSR has CN `papaya`. I'm looking to add some local domain structure with `subjectAltName`, but browsers are rejecting the added domains.

This is my `openssl.cnf` used for signing:

```
[req]
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = v3_req

[v3_req]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = papaya
DNS.2 = *.papaya
DNS.3 = localhost
```

Connecting to https://localhost or https://whatever.papaya then makes Firefox 45 puke with

```
localhost uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is only valid for the following names: papaya, *.papaya, localhost 
Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
```

I'd say this is some confusing stuff, since the error message seems to indicate everything is correct. Only https://papaya works though.

To add to the confusion, on Chrome 49, https://localhost also works. Unfortunately https://whatever.papaya still does not.

I've used this exact procedure to output multiple real-world FQDN certs, but never for local single word domains, hence the confusion.

What am I missing?

Comment: More http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6873/can-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-be-issued-for-a-second-level-domain/

Comment: The solution to my problem is likely going to be creating a parallel local "throwaway" CA, that makes it easy to add new domains. My master CA is attached to a smart card, which may be too inconvenient to use for this purpose.

Comment: And finally, http://xca.sourceforge.net is a great piece of certificate and authority management software.